# Making/Implementing a Iterator for arraylists- Java

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator, iterable

Code for MyArrayList class:

```
public class MyArrayList implements Iterable<Object> {
public static final int DEFAULT_SIZE = 5;
public static final int EXPANSION = 5;
private int capacity;
private int size;
private Object[] items;
private int currentSize;

public MyArrayList() {
    size = 0;
    capacity = DEFAULT_SIZE;
    items = new Object[DEFAULT_SIZE];
    this.currentSize = items.length;
}

@Override
public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
    Iterator<Object> it = new Iterator<Object>() {
        private int currentIndex = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return currentIndex < currentSize && items[currentIndex] != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            return items[currentIndex++];
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

    };
    return it;
}


        private void expand() {
            Object[] newItems = new Object[capacity + EXPANSION];
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) newItems[j] = items[j];
            items = newItems;
            capacity = capacity + EXPANSION;
        }

        public void add(Object obj) {
            try {
                if (size >= capacity) this.expand();
                items[size] = obj;
                size++;
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("There is an error adding this word." + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public int size() {
            return size;
        }

        public Object get(int index) {
            try {
                return items[index];
            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("There is an error getting this word from position: " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return items[index];
        }


        public void add(int index, Object obj) {
            try {
                if (size >= capacity) this.expand();
                for (int j = size; j > index; j--) items[j] = items[j - 1];
                items[index] = obj;
                size++;
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.println("There is an error adding this word to array at position: " + e.getMessage() + ".");
            }
        }


        public boolean remove(Object obj) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                if (obj.equals(this.get(j))) {
                    for (int k = j; k < size - 1; k++) items[k] = items[k + 1];
                    items[size] = null;
                    size--;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public Object remove(int index) {
            try {
                Object result = this.get(index);
                for (int k = index; k < size - 1; k++) items[k] = items[k + 1];
                items[size] = null;
                size--;
                return result;
            } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                System.out.print("There is an error removing this word from position " + e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
 }

 }
```

Code for main method. (adding data)

```
 public class adding{

static MyArrayList zoo = new MyArrayList() {


public static void printZoo() {
    System.out.print("The zoo now holds " + zoo.size() + " animals: ");
    for (int j = 0; j < zoo.size(); j++) System.out.print(zoo.get(j) + " ");
    System.out.println();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String[] zooList = {"Cheetah", "Jaguar", "Leopard", "Lion", "Panther", "Tiger"};

    for (String x: zooList) zoo.add(x);
    printZoo();

    System.out.printf("\nTesting the iterator\n>> ");
    Iterator it = zoo.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(it.next() + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.printf("\nTesting the iterator again without resetting\n>> ");
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(it.next() + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.printf("\nTesting the iterator again after resetting\n>> ");
    it = zoo.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(it.next() + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.printf("\nTesting for-each loop\n>> ");
    for(Object animal: zoo) System.out.print(animal + " ");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("\nLetting all the animals escape");
    while (zoo.size()>0) zoo.remove(0);
    printZoo();

    System.out.printf("\nTesting the iterator with an empty list\n>> ");
    it = zoo.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(it.next() + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("\nTest complete");


}
 }
```

**So I need to make a correct Iterator so it can print out the contents of the arraylists using the while loops.**

**OUTPUT**

```
 The zoo now holds 6 animals: Cheetah Jaguar Leopard Lion Panther Tiger 

 Testing the iterator
 >> Cheetah Jaguar Leopard Lion Panther  //Works fine

 Testing the iterator again without resetting
 >>  // This is still blank

Testing the iterator again after resetting
>> Cheetah Jaguar Leopard Lion Panther 

Testing for-each loop
>> Cheetah Jaguar Leopard Lion Panther // Works fine.

Letting all the animals escape
The zoo now holds 0 animals: //Is there a way to remove by changing the MyArraylist class instead of changing the added class?

Testing the iterator with an empty list
>> Tiger  //Still inaccurate.
```

Pretty sure the logic of my iterator from the MyArrayList class is not accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using

```
  static MyArrayList zoo = new MyArrayList() {
        @Override
        public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
            return null;
        }
    };
```

you declare a new anonymous inner class which overrides the iterator method you defined in MyArrayList. So just construct zoo as

```
static MyArrayList zoo = new MyArrayList();
```

and it should be fine (apart from the expand method which is missing in the snippet you posted)

Comment: Ahh forgot to delete that extra section. Thanks very much.  Now for some reason it's not iterating 100% properly. I will post output. ( added expand btw)

Comment: i added the changes to hopefully fix these issues

Comment: Ok... seems to be a little bit of a mess there ;-) Using two variables to keep track of the size of your MyArrayList class (i.e. size and currentsize) is most certainly the root of the error. I would advise you to use a list instead of an array to keep track of the items in "MyArrayList". Doing so you can get rid of all the code copying around your array contents. This also would allow you to get rid of the currentsize variable as you can always query the list about the current size.

Answer (score 0):

You just override the `Iterable<Object>` interface in your main class which return a null iterator.

Change your code

```
static MyArrayList zoo = new MyArrayList() {
@Override
public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
    return null;
}};
```

To

```
static MyArrayList zoo = new MyArrayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Well.. It does exactly what it is supposed to do.

You have overridden the iterator() method  with a null return as you declared zoo (Adding.java line 7-12).

So the iterator is null and java will throw a NullPointerException as soon as you try to acess a method of the Iterator.

2 little things to notice. Please provide all methods (expand() was missing) and follow the name convetions (class names with capital letter).

Comment: Okay thanks sorted everything out. Another problem arises which I added to description